# Battery charging issue (3rd contact) - cordless drill

Tags: battery-charging

I have two cordless 18v drills with very similar batteries that fit in each.
One has the third (memory/info) contact, the other just + and -.
The charger of the two contact battery has stopped working. My problem is the charger with the third contact won't charge the battery with just the two contacts.
Is there a work-around for this problem?
Thanks.
Ian

Answer (score 1):

It's a safety feature. Thus not you can't work around that.

The third signal can be of two kind:

- Analog. it's a connection to an internal temperature sensor to monitor the temperature during the charging. Some charger use that temperature information to stop the charging process.
- Digital. the charger can discuss with the internal fuel gauge and protection circuit of the battery.

In either case, if the charger don't have access to theses information, it wont work.

Comment: Thanks Blup. What if I connect a wire from the memory contact of the charger to the memory contact of the battery when it's drained, and then put the other two contact battery in the charger? Do you think that would work?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "work". It may start the charging process, but might not be able to decide to stop it. 3 thing can happens: 1) Nothing - no charge, 2) Correct charging 3) Trigger of the battery protection circuit.

Which one will happens ? I don't know, it depends on the design of the charger and the battery pack.

Comment: How will one wire from the "other" battery give the signal? surely it is referenced to either the + or -...

Comment: Thanks Blup and Mike. Will have a go and post the result. Cheers!

Comment: Well, don't ask me how but it worked and the battery charged. Thanks very much for the help and advice Blup and Mike - appreciated!